# Django: Object Filtering from ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I have a Question & Answer model, where anyone can answer a question & also follow a question.

```
# question model
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)

# answer model
class Answer(models.Model):
    text_answer = models.TextField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I filter through `Answer` if `request.user` is followers list?

I tried `Answer.objects.filter(question.followers=request.user)` but it didn't work.

Comment: Aren't you looking for `question__followers=request.user`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django, queryset filter ManyToManyField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313941/django-queryset-filter-manytomanyfield)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: @Bono No, it's not working